# Plot Bar Chart with Date as x lablel and count on y

Tags: r, plot

New to RStudio, so apologies if this is crazy easy.

I have the following data

```
       date          value 
1 ..... 2014-12-10..... -0.26315789

2.....  2014-12-11..... 0.23849372

3.....  2014-12-12.....-0.09166667

4.....  2014-12-15.....0.02358491

5.....  2014-12-16 .....0.02824859

6.....  2014-12-17.....-0.24848485

7.....  2014-12-18.....-0.51388889
```

I want to plot a bar chart of this. 
What I have currently is

```
 x <- df$date
 y <- df$value
 a <- ggplot(df,aes(y)) + geom_bar(width=.8)
```

But the plot is not what I'm looking for. I want the date on the x column and the bars to scale to the values on those dates.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated- 
(I added the dots as I thought it wouldn't display correctly on the post)

Answer (score 0):

Was able to work it out myself in the end...

If you call the plot function like this or whatever styling you want

a <- ggplot(df,aes(x,y), xlab = "Date") + geom_point(stat="identity", size = 7, colour = "darkgreen") + xlab("Date") + ylab("Forecast")
a

Then add to that function 'a' by calling:
b <- a + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack")
b